# Bounds on unit disc imply boundedness at origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D_{1}(0)$ the open unit disc. Let $\Gamma_{1} = \{z : |z| = 1, x>0, y>0\}$ where $z = x+iy$ and define $\Gamma_{2}, \Gamma_{3}, \Gamma_{4}$ similarly. On $\Gamma_{i}$, $|f(z)| \le M_{i}$. How can we show $|f(0)|\le (M_{1}M_{2}M_{3}M_{4})^{\frac{1}{4}}$?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing some convention here, but why can I not define $f$ arbitrarily on the unit circle? There is no continuity assumption. So, choose $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ on the open unit disk, and $f(e^{i\theta}) = 0$, for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $g(x) = f(x) f(ix) f(-x) f(-ix)$.

Comment: Is there some implied connection between the behavior of $f$ on the unit circle with the behavior inside the unit disk? (I'm referring to the question, not your answer.)

Comment: However, I like your approach.

Comment: Yes, we do have to be careful.  My solution would be correct if $f$ extends to a continuous function on the closed unit disk.
If you only assume it's holomorphic in the open unit disk, there is no connection with the behaviour on the circle.

Comment: Even if the statements about $f(z)$ for $z \in \Gamma_j$ refer to limits (but not as $z \to 1$, which is not in any $\Gamma_j$), it is not enough: consider $f(z) = e^{1/(1-z)}$.

Comment: Is the hint suggesting that for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ we have $f(x)\leq M_1$, $f(ix)\leq M_2$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, etc.?

Comment: @JohnAdamski: no, the hint is not suggesting that at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) states that either f(0)=0 or
$$\log|f(0)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta-\sum_{k=1}^n\log(\frac{r}{|a_k|})$$
for any function $f$ analytic on a region containing $\overline{B(0;r)}$ with zeros $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ in $B(0;r)$, repeated according to multiplicity.

Therefore, for any $0<r<1$ we have
$$\log|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta\leq\frac{1}{4}(\log(m_1)+\log(m_2)+\log(m_3)+\log(m_4),$$
where $m_1=\sup_{0<\theta<\pi/2}\{|f(re^{i\theta}|\}$, $m_2=\sup_{\pi/2<\theta<\pi}\{|f(re^{i\theta}|\}$, etc.

Letting $r\rightarrow1$, we have 
$$\log|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{4}(\log(M_1)+\log(M_2)+\log(M_3)+\log(M_4))$$
$$|f(0)|\leq(M_1M_2M_3M_4)^\frac{1}{4}$$